# Dynamics 365 Web Api Integration returning only guids' not friendly names

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to Integrate Dynamics 365 from another application and have registered the CRM on Azure app registry got the Client ID & secret and managed to call the CRM Web Api end point successfully. However its' returning the GUID's of the lookup fields but not the formatted values. I'm actually looking for the formatted values / friendly names of the lookup fields.

```
[{
"@odata.etag": "W/\"2805721\"",
"address2_addresstypecode": 1,
"merged": false,
"statecode": 0,
"exchangerate": 1.0000000000,
"name": "test_5e09f2e6-1b93-48c9-a795-d8e387ef56b5",
"opendeals": 0,
"modifiedon": "2020-07-17T20:55:51Z",
"_owninguser_value": "63d36f17-80c4-448e-a3cf-1406cb722aca",
"openrevenue_state": 1,
"accountratingcode": 1,
"marketingonly": false,
"donotphone": false,
"preferredcontactmethodcode": 1,
"_ownerid_value": "63d36f17-80c4-448e-a3cf-1406cb722aca",
"customersizecode": 1,
"openrevenue_date": "2020-07-19T21:11:45Z",
"openrevenue_base": 0.0000000000,
"businesstypecode": 1,
"donotemail": false,
"address2_shippingmethodcode": 1,
"address1_addressid": "f31956ee-e8f7-4769-bd01-0ff34e66b9b4",
"address2_freighttermscode": 1,
"statuscode": 1,
"createdon": "2020-07-17T20:55:51Z",
"msdyn_travelchargetype": 690970003,
"opendeals_state": 1,
"versionnumber": 2805721,
"donotpostalmail": false,
"openrevenue": 0.0000000000,
"donotsendmm": false,
"donotfax": false,
"donotbulkpostalmail": false,
"creditonhold": false,
"_transactioncurrencyid_value": "b574b624-5fc8-ea11-a812-002248006c8d",
"accountid": "93c71621-bd9f-e711-8122-000d3a2ba2ea",
"donotbulkemail": false,
"_modifiedby_value": "63d36f17-80c4-448e-a3cf-1406cb722aca",
"followemail": true,
"shippingmethodcode": 1,
"_createdby_value": "63d36f17-80c4-448e-a3cf-1406cb722aca",
"territorycode": 1,
"msdyn_taxexempt": false,
"participatesinworkflow": false,
"accountclassificationcode": 1,
"_owningbusinessunit_value": "13822185-4cc8-ea11-a812-002248006c8d",
"address2_addressid": "921bf6ca-e8ac-4b72-a61a-6e65a683c3e1",
"opendeals_date": "2020-07-19T21:11:45Z",}, ....]
```

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to the tag [tag:dynamics-365-operations], unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Include a header in the Request --- "Prefer" : "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"